# AWS S3 + Cloudfront (or other CDN) : How to make multiple aliases URL to same file?

Tags: url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, cdn

I plan to use S3 + Cloudfront for hosting static images for an e-commerce web app. Each user-uploaded image can be used for several end points.

Example user actions in the back office :

- Uploads image `flower.jpg` in his *media library*
- Creates a flower product with id `1`
- Creates another flower product with id `2`
- Assign image `flower.jpg` to illustrate both product

I was thinking about a *convention over configuration* mechanism such as :

- Uploaded images have a unique name, like `flower.jpg` in this case
- When used to illustrate any item, use a convention like : point `p1.jpg` and `p2.jpg` to `flower.jpg`, the same way symlinks work

All three following URLs would return the same file :

- `http://aws-s3/my_app/flower.jpg`
- `http://aws-s3/my_app/p1.jpg`
- `http://aws-s3/my_app/p2.jpg`

**Can I do that with AWS ?**

I did not find any such thing in the API docs, except for the temporary public URL, which comes with two no-go : 1, they expire, 2, I cannot chose the URL

**Can I do that with another CDN ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that to accomplish such a thing your best bet is going to be to use [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) <sup>[*(pricing)*](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)</sup> with [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

My reasoning is that S3, as you say, doesn't allow for redirect URLs. To accomplish what you want, you would need to actually upload the file to each place, which would greatly increase your costs.

However, what you *can* do is use EC2 as a webserver. I'll leave it up to you to decide on your configuration, but you can do anything on EC2 you could do on any server - like set up redirects.

For reference, [here's a good tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html) on setting up Apache on Ubuntu Server, and [here's one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/apache-aliasing-and-redirection/) on setting up Apache redirects.

Comment: That is what I was actually trying to avoid : manage a list of images redirections in my (already existing) node+mongodb EC2 app :-)

Comment: S3 actually does support redirections since Q4 2012. See: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/04/web-page-redirects-on-amazon-s3-hosted-websites/ .

Answer (score 0):

I think, now you can use S3, Route53 and Cloudfront to achieve the same. The question seems to however aged, but thought it may be useful for someone looking now.